# TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i want if the ch0 checkbox in html is checked , send commands to port .

but code can not recognize html element in node js.

and occured error ( typeerror : cannot read property 'checked' of null)

i use jsdom but i think it can't have no effect

how can i solve it?

```
-run.js- (module)

module.exports=async function(){

var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var JSDOM = jsdom.JSDOM;
var dom = new JSDOM();
var document = dom.window.document;
console.log('1');

await delay(1000);

var serialport = require('serialport');
var port = new serialport("/dev/ttyACM0",{ autoOpen: false});

port.close(function(){
    delete port ;
});

await delay(1000);

port = new serialport("/dev/ttyACM0" , {baudRate:9600} );

await delay(1000);

var ch0 = document.getElementById('ch0') ;

if (ch0.checked == true ){
    setInterval(() => port.write("enable 15\n"+"mon 0\n"+"meas? 1\n"),1000);
}``

-index.ejs- (html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= title %></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />

</head>

<body>
<div style="height: 200px ; border: 1px   solid  blue ; " > 
<input type="checkbox" id="ch0" value="1">ch0

<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start(1)">

</div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var socket = io.connect();  

    function start(data)
    {
        socket.emit('start');
    }

  </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: `var ch0 = document.getElementById('ch0') ;` is executed before `<input type="checkbox" id="ch0" value="1">` exists - you need to wait for the DOM to be ready before trying to access it ... or, move your javascript to the bottom of the body

Comment: but The structure I entered is index.ejs (socket.emit('start')) -> app.js (socket.on('start')) , (run()) -> run.js .. and  html's script is already located at bottom of the body

Comment: is it? it's hard to tell seeing as you've posted a single code block which I now see is at least two different files - still, for some reason `ch0 = document.getElementById('ch0')` is getting called "too early"

Comment: Then, should I give delay before ch0 is defined? Or how to wait for ready to access html ?

Comment: sorry, JSDOM is not something I'm familiar with - dealing with asynchronism using "delays" is a recipe for disaster - instead, can you add a `dom.window.addEventListener('load', () => {... your code that needs the dom goes here ...})`

Comment: Wait, you have node code running on the server and think it will work with the browser? If that is the case, that is not how it works.

Comment: @epascarello Is not it possible i use socket io  , javascript and html?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an important observation:

What you've done here is the fastest way to create a memory leak under the Chromium engine...

```
 var ch0 = document.getElementById('ch0') ;
```

You already have an identifier by that name and then create a pointer in memory that points to the same-named identifier!

So later, if you decide you're done with that element and assign...

```
Ch0=null;
```

...so as to attract the Garbage Collector to dispose the element’s memory... have a guess what gets disposed?

None of them! Because the Garbage Collector has no idea which of the two identifiers you're referring to and can never decide for you.

In future just use your element’s identifier directly. You don't need to declare another variable to point to it.